# Dynamic transpile and serve React application on expressjs

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs

The usual process of deploying a `react` application is simple when using `webpack` to handle the code transpilation and the final result is one `.js` app which contains all the css/js/html. But I have an application which needs some data from client's request to express server.

For example I want to get a `userid` from the request, and based on that provide some data to `App` component and then, provide a `.js` file (like what webpack provides) that contains the App and user specific data.

I've tried, to user `babel-core/register` and `react-dom/server.renderToString`, but it just provides to `html` and `css` and not the `js` code that is necessary to make the app work. I have to load those codes separately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite common problem.
It is better to solve it a little different then you tried (you don't want to force your user to wait ~10s to build bundle for him)

1. There is one universal build bundle for all users (or few - for example one for normal users and second for admin users)
2. Your server gets request from your user with special parameters for example `userid`
3. Your server render start html page as response to this request - for example index.html. This file should have `<script src` to bundle js for your user. Source path should be dynamically build by server to point exact js bundle (if there are more then one). It should also have javascript global object with parameters from server which should be visible by your components.
   For example index.html could look like (you could do it differently, maybe without creating global object. I hope that you get general sense of this idea).  :

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8">
>   <title>Document</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <div id="root"></div>
> <script>
>   __CONFIG__ = {
>     someObject1: '<!-- @echo someObject1 -->',
>     someObject2: '<!-- @echo someObject2 -->',
>     userid: '<!-- @echo userid -->',
>   }
> </script>
> <script src="<!-- @echo SOME_PATH -->/static/bundle.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Now your component could check global variable **CONFIG** .
But I suggest not to use it in your normal components!
Create bootstrap component which loads your normal react app and which is something like bridge between your app and environment. 
Read global config in this bootstrap component and then pass it as props to your app.

This bootstrap component could look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';
const config = window.__CONFIG__;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    config={config}
  />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Edit:
This is also good way if you have to set initial state based on db or to tell react to do something. 
For this I add additional global variable `__INIT__`

Comment: The load time was the bottleneck that forced me to choose a approach close to what you suggested. I use that user id in a `fetch()` call to retrieve users data. Thank you...